# Polarity for a 2-way T shaped faston blade terminal housing?

Tags: connector

What is the correct polarity for these two way faston terminal housings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard as far as I know. Since they are typically used for internal cabling just match the male with the female

Answer (score 2):

As Lorenzo Marcantonio say, there is no standart. But for determines you can use standard from for example xt60 connectors, which flat side is always positive terminal.
[image: xt60]

Answer (score 1):

I found the following recommendation. The recommendation appears to be followed by a few items I checked: a couple of transceiver radios, and Mitsubishi solenoids which use the T shaped housings.

https://www.raynet-uk.net/technical/powercon.htm